# How to access a specific port of the ec2 instance from another machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I want to send data from my instance to a production server(aws ec2) on the port 8093. I edited the security group to have a new rule: Custom TCP rule with TCP protocol which accepts requests from anywhere and the port range is 8093. Still, when I make the curl request using the public IP of the production ec2 server, the operation gets timed out. I have several minutes to be sure that the changes take place but in vain.

I tried reading some of the ec2 support threads but none addressed this issue.

Following is the current status of the security group:
[image: Current inbound rules of the security group]

Following is the command that I am using:

```
➜  ~ curl a.b.c.d:8093
curl: (7) Failed to connect to a.b.c.d port 8093: Operation timed out
```

I expect the result to be usual, as if when I do the same command on the ec2 machine itself: `curl localhost:8093`.

Comment: Are you sure that your web server on prod server is listening for traffic from all the sources.?This has nothing to do with AWS

Comment: How can I make sure of that? I have attached the pic in the question, it states that the source can be any address and port. Anything that I am missing?

Comment: What webserver are you using on your prod server?

Comment: Nginx reverse proxy and no webserver. Just a port that is constantly receiving data from a python script. On that server, I am able to fetch the data using `curl localhost:8093`.

Comment: Do you have  "allow all;" in you nginx locaiton

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have allowed traffic on the server in the windows firewall policy.
Hope this helps.